# Retrieve a Softlayer user's permission via API

Tags: python, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'd like to retrieve a user's current permissions via Softlayer's Python API, ideally a list containing permissions as they'd be seen on the user portal.

I've tried the method [under User_Customer service](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_User_Customer/getPermissions), which reports back with the following error:

`SoftLayer.exceptions.SoftLayerAPIError: SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception): Object does not exist to execute method on. (SoftLayer_User_Customer::getPermissions)`

I'm aware that a header may need to be set for that particular API call, but I couldn't find a source that explains how to set the headers in the Python API.

I've also tried calling [this Account service method](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getPermissionRoles). Which succeeds, but returns a list of users under the account and not the information I expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can see examples about the use of the python client:

https://softlayer.github.io/python/

particulary about the permissions associated to an user you can see this example:

https://softlayer.github.io/python/set_permission/

```
permissions = self.client['User_Customer'].getPermissions(id=user_id)
        print("=== OLD PERMISSIONS ===")
        self.printPermissions(permissions)
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks for your response, the examples link is really useful.

Regarding the question, I've tried the suggested code, which returns the following exception: `SoftLayer.exceptions.SoftLayerAPIError: SoftLayerAPIError(SOAP-ENV:Server): Internal Error`.


I've also tried the following REST call: `curl -su <user_id>:<api_key> https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_User_Customer/<user_id>/Permissions.json`. 
And the respective response: `{"error":"Internal Error","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"}`

Thanks.

Comment: this should works finecurl -su <user_id>:<api_key> https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_User_Customer/<user_id>/getPermissions.json I think the error you are getting is because somehow your request contains additional characters which are not visible.

Comment: I pasted the command in Vi and toggled `:set list` to see all hidden characters and there were none. Also tried running it as a shell script with the same effect. Also tried with a different pair of valid credentials and no effect.

Comment: but when I copied your comand it di not work I had to write it again, that's why I think some charcters are hidden in your request.